# Ncurses not reporting mouse movements after columns 94

Tags: terminal, mouseevent, ncurses

With the following example, I am able to get the mouse position inside my terminal until column 94. Where is the limitation?

```
#include <curses.h>

int main()
{
    initscr();
    cbreak();
    noecho();

    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
    mousemask(ALL_MOUSE_EVENTS, NULL);

    MEVENT event;
    for (;;)
        if (wgetch(stdscr) == KEY_MOUSE && getmouse(&event) == OK)
            mvprintw(0, 0, "Mouse at row=%03d and column=%03d", event.y, event.x);
}
```

Tested in:

- Windows Terminal (WSL2)
- cmd.exe (WSL2)

But it is working in :

- mintty (WSL2)

What am I missing?

In all terminal, I get the same result by manually enabling mouse reporting with `echo -e "\e[?1000;1006;1015h"`. So it seems Ncurses is using something else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ncurses uses the terminal description to determine if the terminal supports xterm's [1006 mouse-mode](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h3-Extended-coordinates).  It looks at the **`XM`** flag (see [`user_caps(5)`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/user_caps.5.html)):

> The XM capability has a single parameter.  If nonzero, the  mouse
> protocol  should  be enabled.  If zero, the mouse protocol should
> be disabled.  ncurses inspects this capability if it is  present,
> to  see whether the 1006 protocol is used.  If so, it expects the
> responses to use the SGR 1006 xterm mouse protocol.

To see that flag, you can use `infocmp`, e.g.,

```
infocmp -1x |grep XM,
```

to see if it is defined.  For `mintty`, you might see this:

```
$ infocmp -1x mintty | grep XM
        XM=\E[?1006;1000%?%p1%{1}%=%th%el%;,
```

For those others, it helps to know what `TERM` is set to (also, the version of ncurses, since it [*could*](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/NEWS.html#t20181124) be too old).

That **`1015`** in the question bears comment: that is an rxvt-unicode feature, which is not recognized by Windows Terminal.  Nor is it mentioned in the documentation for [Windows cmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences).  It is implemented in PuTTY (also xterm, though PuTTY's implementation differs from xterm).  In both PuTTY/xterm, that **`1006`** which precedes the **`1015`** in the `echo` command will cause those terminals to use xterm's 1006 ("SGR mode"), which is implemented by Windows Terminal.  If you had omitted the **`1006`**, then it would not work with ncurses, because the protocols differ—and ncurses does not have support for the **`1015`** encoding.